# Why controller no works only in Html.PartialAsync?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Now I have a controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Location()
        {
            Models.LocationModel Location = null;
            //some logic
            return View(Location);
        }
```

And here is the View:

```
@model Vishdo.Models.LocationModel
<div>
    <h5>@Model.City</h5>
    <span>@Model.Name</span>
    <span>@Model.Phone</span>
</div>
```

When I access the View by the URL(https://localhost:44372/home/location) directly, all works well.

Now I add it into the `_Layout.cshtml` like this:

```
@Html.PartialAsync("/Views/Home/Location.cshtml")
```

After it ran, it reports an error on the View `Location.cshtml`:

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=Sample.Views
  StackTrace:
   at AspNetCore.Views_Home_Location.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext() in E:\Project\Sample\Views\Home\Location.cshtml:line 3
```

I added a breakpoint in the Location controller and found it never works. So the Model always is null and reports this error.

In addition, I add this into the `_Layout.cshtml` for this feature is needed by all the pages and the `_Layout.cshml` has not a controller so I have to do it like this.

What's wrong with my code? How can I solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since @Html.PartialAsync() will not trigger the controller action so you've multiple options here to solve your problem.
1- you should get the Location model from any service and pass it to @Html.PartialAsync() like below:

```
@inject LocationService locationService
@{
    var locationModel = locationService.GetLocation();
}
```

and then pass this locationModel to @Html.PartialAsync()

```
@Html.PartialAsync("/Views/Home/Location.cshtml", locationModel );
```

2- Use ViewComponent as described above.
3- Use @Html.Action() by implementing this as a HtmlHelper extension. Refer this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44541924/how-to-use-html-action-instead-of-viewcomponent-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: I am trying the first way. The model transfer to the View successfully while finally, it renders a strange string "
                System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.IHtmlContent]
                ".

Comment: All right, I should add a.Result after the PartialAsync. It works now.

Answer (score 2):

> I added a breakpoint in the Location controller and found it never works. So the Model always is null and reports this error.

It's the expected behavior, `@Html.PartialAsync()` will not trigger the controller action, it directly search the partival view under the view folder.

In addition, you can achieve it with `ViewComponent`. I made a demo like below:

1.Create a folder named `ViewComponents` in your project, and create a class named `LocationViewComponent`

[image]

```
public class LocationViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
    {
        var Location = new LocationModel()
        {
            City = "AAA",
            Name = "BBB",
            Phone = "CCC"
        };
        return View(Location);
    }
}
```

2.The default view name for a view component is Default.cshtml, add it to the Shared folder like below:

[image]

Default.cshtml

```
@model LocationModel

<div>
    <h5>@Model.City</h5>
    <span>@Model.Name</span>
    <span>@Model.Phone</span>
</div>
```

3.Call the ViewComponent in the layout:

```
<div class="container">
    <main role="main" class="pb-3">
        @RenderBody()
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("Location")
    </main>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

For more details, you can refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: By the way, as you said @Html.PartialAsync() will not trigger the controller action. Is there any other method to achieve this without using the ViewComponent?

Comment: The options gave by @Munesh Kumar are also feasible.