# Return json to partial view in core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I would like to create a view that would contain a different view. I've never used json before. How i can do this and How can I format the json data in the view?

My first function "Details" is to retrieve a object from the database and return view "Details.cshtml". In this view I want generates a partial view ("Stats.cshtml"). And now I want to generate a partial view with the data downloaded in the json format inside the Stats function.

**Controller**

```
public IActionResult Details(int? id = 1)
{
  var person = _context.Persons.Find(id);

  return View(champion);
}

public IActionResult Stats()
{
  var json = new WebClient().DownloadString("url");

  return Json(s);
}
```

**View - Details.cshtml**

```
@model Person

<div class=row">
  <div class="col-sm-5"> @Model.Name </div>
  <div class="col-sm-5"> @Html.Partial("Stats") </div>
</div>
```

**View - Stats.cshtml**

```
<h2>Stats</h2>
<div> here I want to put in a json field </div>
```

When I run "Stats" function from the address ***localhost/Home/Stats*** I get the result in json, but when I run "Details" function I get view "Details" and "Stats" without the json value.

Comment: I do it, but in view. I dont know is it good

`@{
        @using Newtonsoft.Json;
        @using System.Net;

        var s = new WebClient().DownloadString("url");
        var yourViewModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<App.Models.ViewModel.Person>(s);
    }`
  
`@Html.Partial("Stats", yourViewModel)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to render a partial, you have many options, by your code,

1. the simplest one is: move your Stats code to Details action

   ```
   public ActionResult Details()
   {
       ...//prepare your person viewModel

       var result = new WebClient().DownloadString("url");
       var stats = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourViewModel>(result);

       //you have 2 options to return data
       yourPersonModel.Stats=stats ; //<== you have to change PersonViewModel
       //or ViewBag.Stats=stats; 

       return View(yourPersonModel);
   }
   ```

then in Details.cshtml:

```
@Html.Partial("Stats", ViewBag.Stats or Model.Stats)//by your choice before.
```

2. Since Html.Action is removed, but ViewComponent comes in Core, you cannot directly call it right now, but this link will tell you how to make it back: [@Html.Action in Asp.Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26916664/html-action-in-asp-net-core)

   ```
   public ActionResult Stats()
   {
       var result = new WebClient().DownloadString("url");
       var yourViewModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourViewModel>(result);
       return PartialView(yourViewModel);
   }
   ```

add the following code in your View - Stats.cshtml:

```
@model YourViewModel
```

then in Details.cshtml:

```
@Html.Action("Stats")
```

Be aware that **`Html.Action` cannot call `async` actions, be careful to use it.**

3. the next solution is to use new feature ViewComponent, here is details:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.1
4. the last one will not be what you expected: use AJAX to load this partial page on page Details is loaded to client

Comment: I get error in line: `@Html.Partial("Stats")`. _InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'App.Models.Person', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'App.Models.ViewModel.Person'._

Comment: Change `@Html.Partial("Stats")` to `@Html.Action("Stats")`, I forgot mention it.

Comment: Oops, if you are using ASP.NET core, you cannot use `Html.Acton` which is removed. give me time to modify my answer., but you can follow this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26916664/html-action-in-asp-net-core

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is very wide and helpful. I start the adventure with .net and didn't know that the view components exist ;)