# how to render a partial view from controller in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, partial-views

I have an action in the controller to load data for `Partial view` as below:

```cs
    public async Task<IActionResult> ParentTutorCountByLocation()
    {
        var result = await this.dashboardService.GetParentTutorCountPerLocation();
        return this.PartialView("Dashboard/ParentTutorCountByLocation", result);
    }
```

I've to call it over another view:

tried, renderPartialAsync, Partial

```html
<div class="row">
    <partial name="ParentTutorCountByLocation" />
</div>
```

it is load the partial but without data not sure how i can do it. (can't use viewcomponents and ajax)

Comment: Why not pass a `model` explictly e.g. `<partial name="ParentTutorCountByLocation" model="@TheModelForThePartialView" />`?

Comment: _“can't use viewcomponents”_ – *Why*? That’s exactly what view components are for. Partials cannot run their own logic in a controller-like action.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like `Html.Action` to render partial view from the controller. Unfortunately, ASP.NET Core doesn't support this out of the box. You can find `Html.Action` implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26916664/html-action-in-asp-net-core)

Once you implement, you can do something like this.

```
@Html.Action("YourPartialView")
```