# Migrating .NET Core 2.1 to .NET 6.0+

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I'm trying to upgrade a .NET Core 2.1 project to .NET 6.0+.

I see some different behavior in both versions.

**Error:**

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
>
> WebRequestContext.Localization.get returned null.

I would like to understand if is it expected. In the past migrated from ASP.NET MVC on .NET 4.8 to .NET Core 2.1 and used this answer code [@Html.Action in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26916664/html-action-in-asp-net-core).

Everything works fine in .NET Core 2.1, but now I'm upgrading the project to .NET 6.0 my project is not working for certain functionality.

Here is my code reference for `WebRequestContext`:

```
public class WebRequestContext
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
  
    public WebRequestContext(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        Current = this;
    }

    public static WebRequestContext Current { get; private set; }
  
    public Localization Localization
    {
        get
        {
            return (Localization)GetFromContextStore("Localization");
        }
        set
        {
            AddToContextStore("Localization", value);
        }
    }

    protected object GetFromContextStore(string key)
    {
       return _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Items[key];
    }

    protected object AddToContextStore(string key, object value)
    {
        if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext == null) return value;
        _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Items[key] = value;
        return value;
    }
}
```

I have initialized this in `ServiceCollection` like this.

```
    services.AddSingleton<WebRequestContext, WebRequestContext>();            
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    services.AddTransient<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
```

In my project many places in the View and also in the `HtmlHelperExtensions` trying to access this value. At the start of the application, these values are getting stored as expected. I can see this value is accessible at the controller level. In the view if I try to access the `@Html.DxaRegion("Header")` custom extension action after calling this `RenderActionAsync` method this original `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext` value is getting reset to null. This behavior is not happening in .NET Core 2.1

Because in many places I have used to access Localization, this value actually stored in the `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Items[key]` getting null.

```
 WebRequestContext.Current.Localization.CultureInfo
```

This is the code block setting the current HTTPContext value to null. but that same works fine in .NET Core 2.1:

```
private static async Task<IHtmlContent> RenderActionAsync(this IHtmlHelper helper, string action, string controller, string area, object parameters = null)
{
        // fetching required services for invocation
        var serviceProvider = helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.RequestServices;
        var actionContextAccessor = helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IActionContextAccessor>();
        var httpContextAccessor = helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        var actionSelector = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IActionSelector>();

        // creating new action invocation context
        var routeData = new RouteData();

        foreach (var router in helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Routers)
        {
            routeData.PushState(router, null, null);
        }

        routeData.PushState(null, new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = controller, action = action, area = area }), null);
        routeData.PushState(null, new RouteValueDictionary(parameters ?? new { }), null);

        //get the actiondescriptor
        RouteContext routeContext = new RouteContext(helper.ViewContext.HttpContext) { RouteData = routeData };
        var candidates = actionSelector.SelectCandidates(routeContext);
        var actionDescriptor = actionSelector.SelectBestCandidate(routeContext, candidates);

        var originalActionContext = actionContextAccessor.ActionContext;
        var originalhttpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;

        try
        {
            var newHttpContext = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextFactory>().Create(helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Features);

            if (newHttpContext.Items.ContainsKey(typeof(IUrlHelper)))
            {
                newHttpContext.Items.Remove(typeof(IUrlHelper));
            }

            newHttpContext.Response.Body = new MemoryStream();
            var actionContext = new ActionContext(newHttpContext, routeData, actionDescriptor);
            actionContextAccessor.ActionContext = actionContext;
            var invoker = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IActionInvokerFactory>().CreateInvoker(actionContext);
            await invoker.InvokeAsync();
            newHttpContext.Response.Body.Position = 0;

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(newHttpContext.Response.Body))
            {
                return new HtmlString(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new HtmlString(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            actionContextAccessor.ActionContext = originalActionContext;
            httpContextAccessor.HttpContext = originalhttpContext;

            if (helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items.ContainsKey(typeof(IUrlHelper)))
            {
                helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items.Remove(typeof(IUrlHelper));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Did anyone face a similar issue? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code fixed this problem:

Instead of using this code.

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Used this code in order to fix my problem

```
public class HttpContextAccessor : IHttpContextAccessor
    {
        private static AsyncLocal<HttpContext> _httpContextCurrent = new AsyncLocal<HttpContext>();
        HttpContext IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext { get => _httpContextCurrent.Value; set => _httpContextCurrent.Value = value; }
    }

services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```